# How to align div to parent div?

Tags: html, css, alignment, vertical-alignment

suppose we have 4 dives.
the first div is outer div.
i want to create a HTML that
the second div size be 50% first and be in middle bottom of first div.
the third div size be 50% second and be in middle left of second div.
the fourth div size be 50% third div and be in middle top of third div.

how can i do it?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried, what is your basic HTML and CSS ?

Comment: @G-Cyrillus some times we need to test the ability of programing languages. it was a test to create my classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this your desired output? It’s made using `position`, `top` and `bottom`, and `translate` to make sure it’s centered right.

```css
.div1 div { /* makes every small div 50% the size of the previous */
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
}
.div1 {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
}
.div2 {
    background-color: green;
    position: relative;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
}
.div3 {
    background-color: pink;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
}
.div4 {
    background-color: lightblue;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
    <div class="div2">
        <div class="div3">
            <div class="div4">
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use `flex`(or grid) and `margin` *instead position*  :

```css
div {
  display: flex;
}

body>div {
  /* sizing : whatever you want to start from */
  height: 90vmin;
  width: 90vmin;
  background: #ed1c24;
}

div div {
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
}

div div {
  background: #22b14c;
  margin: auto auto 0;
}

div div div {
  background: #ffaec9;
  margin: auto auto auto 0;
}

div div div div {
  background: #00a2e8;
  margin: 0 auto auto;
}


/* center the demo */

html {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

body {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this by using the CSS Flexbox and Margin properties.

**index.html**

```
<body>
    <div class="firstdiv">
        <div class="seconddiv">
            <div class="thirddiv">
                <div class="fourthdiv">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**styles.css**

```
div {
    display: flex;
}

.firstdiv {
  background-color: red;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
}

.seconddiv {
  background-color: green;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.thirddiv {
  background-color: pink;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.fourthdiv {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS flexbox below. There are four divs below and you can change the size of the first div. And then the others automatically align and resize themselves.

**HTML file:**

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div id="first">
    <div id="second">
      <div id="third">
        <div id="fourth">
         <p>Text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS file:**

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#first {
    background: #ed1c24;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-end;
    margin: auto;
}

#second {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    background: #22b14c;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#third {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
    background: #ffaec9;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
}

#fourth {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: #00a3e9;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
}
```

Click to see the result of these lines of code:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etmvg.png)